# Use class instance from swift in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class

I'd like to use the data from a class instance which is initialised in my Swift files, over in my Objective-C files. I'm quite new to Objective-C, but it seems that the classes I initialise in either .swift or .m are only accessible from that file type?

Is there any way around this? Using the example below, how would I access *examp.number* in objective-c?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public var examp: exampleClass = exampleClass();    //create an instance of class

@objc public class exampleClass: NSObject {
var number = 0;

}
```

If not, is there a way I can copy the .swift instance to the .m instance?

If not, is there a way I can copy the data from the .swift instance to something else, and then copy that to the .m instance?

Comment: Global Swift variables (such as `examp`) are not available in Objective-C, as documented in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C"

Comment: @MartinR so is there any way around it? Can I give my .m instance the .swift data? Do I need to initialise the .swift class another way?

Comment: Please use capitalized names for classes / structs / enums / protocols.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can use your `examp` instance of Swift `ExampleClass` in your Objective-C code is by passing it to an Objective-C function.  Here is a quick example.

Swift code:

```
    @objc class ExampleClass: NSObject {
        var number = 123;

    }

    var examp: ExampleClass = ExampleClass();    //create an instance of class

    print("The value of examp.number before the call: \(examp.number)")
    MyClassObjC.junkfun(examp) // Call Objective-C method that will change ExampleClass.number
    print("The value of examp.number after the call: \(examp.number)")
```

Objective-C header, this has to be available to Swift via the bridging header:

```
@class ExampleClass;

@interface MyClassObjC : NSObject 

+(void)junkfun:(ExampleClass*)ec;

@end
```

And here is the Objective-C implementation (.m):

```
#import "cli_swift-Swift.h"  // Important: this header is auto-generated; replace cli_swift with
                             // your product name.

@implementation MyClassObjC : NSObject 

+(void)junkfun:(ExampleClass*)ec
{
    puts("In junkfun");
    ec.number = 321;
}

@end
```

The output should be like:

```
The value of examp.number before the call: 123
In junkfun
The value of examp.number after the call: 321
```

This is just a quick example.  Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/ for more info.

Please note that inheritance from `NSObject` is important here.

Comment: "Please note that inheritance from NSObject is important here." It's only important for the visibility of the class name in Objective-C. But inheritance from `NSObject` is not necessary for the object to be able to be passed into and used in Objective-C.